# How can I make a squere image fit the entire screen and avoid scroll?

Tags: html, css, size, fullscreen, photo

I'm know a thing or two about html/css but I'm no pro.
I have a with a image 7,20cm x,7,20cm and it fills my screen size perfecty but when I view it on a larger screen it gets too big so you have the scroll and it doesn't look pleasing...How can i achive the same effect on larger screens? Thank you for all you anwsers in advance.

```
HTML

<body>
<div class="logo">
    <a href="projects.html" class="transition">
      <img src="lg.png" width="40%" alt="" />
    </a>
</div>
<footer>copyright 2016 matic toni</footer>

</body>

CSS

@charset "utf-8";
div {
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}
body {
/* background-image: url(background.jpg);
background-sizce: cover; */
background-color: #F6F6F6;
}

.logo {
padding-top:3%;
}

footer {
font-family:"Proxima";
clear: both;
color: black;
font-size: 100%;
margin-top: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
margin-left: 5%;
text-align: center;

}

li a img {
padding-top: 3%;
}

@font-face {
font-family: Proxima;
src: url(Fonts/Proxima_Regular.otf);
}
img.logo { max-width: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of this

```
background-image: url("background.jpg");
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
overflow: hidden;
```

Note that this is not optimized, but instead organized for ease of modification.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bgimage{
 background: url(http://images.coolestwallpapers.com/user-content/uploads/wall/1280x854/36/091c7f2accfa32c8a9d912928a0220193e962075.jpg) no-repeat center;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgimage">
 
</div>
```

The height and width is dependent on the design needed.

Answer (score 0):

since your code has a footer, image cannot really be 100% height , unless you mean it's own container ?

however, i believe that flex and some use of vertical padding to set a square box, you can do someting close

Idea is an image with a max-height and max-width such as the contain background-size , to get an image that never grows more than it's container height/width, no matter what is the window's ratio.

example

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.logo {
  width: 80vh;/* tune this , you may use calc() too */
  max-width: 80%;/* tune this */
  background: gray;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.logo:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;/* makes a square, */
}
.logo a {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.logo a img {
  width: 100%;/* or height, it's a square one value is enough */
}
footer {
  text-align: center;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <a href="projects.html" class="transition">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200&text=LOGO-@-center" alt="square" /><!--square of any size-->
  </a>
</div>
<footer>copyright 2016 matic toni</footer>
```

if i misunderstood, then it would be much more like a background-size:contain; so another method to set, but again absolute positionning to keep image tag within HTML